AWS Cognito Cookie Session on Subdomains
I'll explain first what I am trying to do because I think that will illustrate the problem better.
I am using Cognito to authenticate users in a subdomain dedicated to it, like: auth.mydomain.com.
I am trying to make the session work for the main domain and other subdomains, like: mydomain.com and app1.mydomain.com. The session is automatically stored in a cookie named cognito created by Cognito Hosted UI. I am looking for a way that I do not need to pass through the auth.mydomain, so if the user visits one page of the app1.mydomain.com the app picks up that the user is logged in and can access their information.
So what I imagined would work is getting the cookie value and authenticating it in my other sites (for example using an useEffect in a react app that checks for the cookie presence and authenticates the user). The problem is that I have no ideia what the value of the cookie is and how to authenticate it.
One approach that probably works would be to just generate a cookie myself in the callback url based on the refresh token. But that seems unecessary since the session cookie already exists.
The cookie is not a jwt token, as I have checked and the format is not of a JWT Token, so I imagine it is some type of hash. Just for caution, I have tried converting it in the jwt official website and using aws functions that worked for the access, id and refresh tokens but that didn't work.
If anyone knows how to get the info from this cookie or any other suggestion for the functionality that would be awesome since I couldn't find any documentation on Cognito cookies.
